# append values to dictionary depending on length?

Tags: python

I have a list of lists `uarfcnrssi2` and a dictionary of lists `band2`. I then have certain conditions under which values from uarfcnrssi2 are added to band2, as shown below:

```
uarfcnrssi2=[[10564, 20, 1],[10637, 26, 1], [10662, 32, 1], [10712, 26, 1], [10837, 15, 1], [10837, 17, 1],
 [2, 10, 13], [3, 18, 13], [44, 12, 13], [10564, 27, 13], [49, 15, 13], [64, 20, 13], [66, 19, 13], [976, 27, 13], [981, 21, 13], [982, 20, 13], [985, 13, 13], [988, 13, 13], [788, 12, 11]]      

band2= {'channel1': 10564, 'channel2': 10589, 'channel3': 10612, 'channel4': 10637,'channel5': 10662, 'channel6': 10687,
'channel7': 10712, 'channel8': 10737, 'channel9': 10762, 'channel10': 10787,'channel11': 10812, 'channel12': 10837, }
var1 = 5
var2 = -190
band2 = {k: [v, v/var1, v/var1+var2] for k, v in band2.iteritems()
```

Code:

```
for k, v in band2.items():
    for i in uarfcnrssi2:
        if v[0] == i[0] and i[2] == 1 and len(v)<=3:
            band2[k].append(i[1])
```

I now have a dictionary like this:

```
{'channel11': [10812, 2162, 1972], 'channel10': [10787, 2157, 1967], 'channel3': [10612, 2122, 1932], 'channel2': [10589, 2117, 1927], 'channel1': [10564, 2112, 1922, 20], 'channel7': [10712, 2142, 1952, 26], 'channel6': [10687, 2137, 1947], 'channel5': [10662, 2132, 1942, 32], 'channel4': [10637, 2127, 1937, 26], 'channel9': [10762, 2152, 1962], 'channel8': [10737, 2147, 1957], 'channel12': [10837, 2167, 1977, 15]}
```

However for the lists that I did not append a 4th item to I want `0` to be appended to the end of each, I have no problem looping again to do this, but is there a way to edit my code above to do that?

EDIT: Way I did it that I want to improve

```
for k, v in band2.items():
    for i in uarfcnrssi2:
        if v[0] == i[0] and i[2] == 1 and len(v)<=3:
            band2[k].append(i[1])

for k, v in band2.items():
    if len(v) <=3:
        band2[k].append(0)
print band2
```

Final output:

```
band2 = {'channel11': [10812, 2162, 1972, 0], 'channel10': [10787, 2157, 1967, 0], 'channel3': [10612, 2122, 1932, 0], 'channel2': [10589, 2117, 1927, 0], 'channel1': [10564, 2112, 1922, 20], 'channel7': [10712, 2142, 1952, 26], 'channel6': [10687, 2137, 1947, 0], 'channel5': [10662, 2132, 1942, 32], 'channel4': [10637, 2127, 1937, 26], 'channel9': [10762, 2152, 1962, 0], 'channel8': [10737, 2147, 1957, 0], 'channel12': [10837, 2167, 1977, 15]}
```

Comment: The code you've shown won't work unless `band2` already has lists as values, but you've shown it with single `int` values instead. Is that a mistake?

Comment: Thanks, I added in a couple missing lines.

Answer (score 0):

OK I understand the issue now. I think you can combine your two loops, like this:

```
for v in band2.values():
    for i1, i2, i3 in uarfcnrssi2:
        if v[0] == i0 and i2 == 1 and len(v) <= 3:
            v.append(i1)
    if len(v) <= 3: # never matched any list values, so add zero instead
        v.append(0)
```

Note that the outer loop is over the `values` of the dictionary, since you were only using the key for indexing (which isn't necessary, since you already have a reference to the value). I've also made the inner loop unpack the three values into individual variables. I suggest giving them meaningful names (I've only used `i0`, `i1` and `i2` because I don't know what the values mean).

Comment: Thanks I will of course use better names when it;s not an example :) Your code doesn't work as intended, I want to append 0 when len <=3 also. so an else won't work. ( I don't understand the second piece of code, will read up on that)

Comment: OK, I guess I don't understand what you're trying to do. Can you update the question with more information about what you're expecting to get in different situations? For instance, can you show a short example list and dictionary that have some values that are short (and so will get appended to) and some that are longer (and so will be skipped)? Please show the desired output for both situations!

Comment: I have appended what the final output should be, as you can see, if there was no corresponding value to add to lists a 0 was added instead. For instance 10787 was in the dictionary but not the list so i had to add a 0 to that entry.

Comment: I've edited in the way I actually did it so that may make it clearer.

Comment: @Paul: I've updated my answer,  which I think will work for you. There's less room for improvement than I thought when I gave my previous answer, but there are still a few ways things can be better than what you have.

Comment: Thanks your code had minor errors but I fixed them and it works!